# where is the latest MongoDB Wire Protocol

Tags: mongodb, protocols

do you know where i can get the latest MongoDB Wire Protocol?
http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/ seems not updated and no further updates yet
i am studying the mongodb's network protocol at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[That](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/) is the latest version of the documentation.

There was a mention of a new write protocol in the [MongoDB Days (NYC-2013) roadmap presentation](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongodb-roapmap) (13:50) for 2.6 but I know of no actual documentation on the new messages/formats.